# net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR in .NET 6

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, iis, http2

I'm developing an API in .NET 6 with 5 five controllers. All controllers are running good, but the deals controller are giving me that error.
When I set the results to .Take(100) then I get the response all right and complete. Only when I call all results that I get the error and only in that deals class. It returns a few results, nothing more then 20, and then It crashes.
The deals data table has 4.2MB, but the organization table has 3.9MB and return the complete response.
I've tried to set ASP buffer limits on IIS, upgrade windows and run in another browsers. Nothing worked yet.
For secrecy reasons of my job, I can't show the json return or data tables.

There's a reason or a way to set this class to return all content without an error?

If you guys know something about this error and need to see the code just ask me out

Comment: "almost five controllers", so four? Seriously though, without any code or anything you're not likely to get an answer

Comment: @HoneyBadger almost could be more or less than 5, I don't remember now how many... Is that important to solve the problem? I ask for any kind suggestion, if you need the code I can post here. It's a way easier than post a bunch of files that don't mean nothing for the question here. Did You know something about the error? Ask me for more info, else you don't need to see the code about a problem you don't even know.

Comment: You will have to show us more on how it crashed. The title itself is far from enough. If you cannot edit the question to share more information due to security concerns (which makes perfect sense), you might open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com .